# What does the word 'worthy' mean in Matthew 10:11?

Tags: matthew, jesus

Matthew 10:11 NASB

> 11 And whatever city or village you enter, inquire who is ***worthy*** in it, and stay [m]at his house until you leave that city.

What does this word refer to in the above text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 1,700 page supplemented American edition of Liddell & Scott has the word 'deserving' for *axios*.

Thayer suggests the idea of 'weighty' - having weight.

It is the same word which Paul uses, when writing to Timothy :

> This is a faithful saying, and **worthy** of all acceptation, that Christ Jesus came into the world to save sinners; of whom I am chief. I Timothy 1:15 KJV.

It is also the same word used by John the Baptist, recorded by Matthew :

> he that cometh after me is mightier than I, whose shoes I am not **worthy** to bear: Matthew 3:11 KJV.

And, again, in Hebrews 3:3 :

> For this [one]('man' is not there in the Greek) was counted **worthy** of more glory than Moses,

The word occurs about forty-five times in the bible (TR) but there is also a word *kataxios* 'to be counted worthy' (about six times) which is an interesting expression of the prefix *kata*, such as :

> rejoicing that they were **counted worthy** to suffer shame for his name Acts 5:41 KJV.

---

I would suggest in this context - Matthew 10:11 - that it is a matter of character. Someone trustworthy. Someone substantial. Not a lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

The word "worthy" is translating the Greek word ἄξιός (axios).

[image]

According to BDAG, this word has two basic meanings:

(1) **pertaining to having a relatively high degree of comparable worth or value, *corresponding, comparable, worthy*,** eg, (a) of price Rom 8:8, (b) generally of any other relation Luke 3:8, Matt 3:8, Acts 26:20, 1 Thess 1:15, 4:9, Luke 23:15, Acts 25:11, 25, 23:29, 26:31, Luke 23:41, (c) impersonal worthwhile, fitting, proper 1 Cor 16:4, 2 Thess 1:3

(2) **pertaining to being correspondingly fitting or appropriate, *worthy, fit, deserving*** (a) in a good sense Matt 10:10, 11, 37, Acts 13:46, Luke 10:7, 1 Tim 5:18, 6:1, etc, (b) in a context in which the evaluation is qualified by unpleasant consequences to the one evaluated, eg, Luke 12:48, Rom 1:32.

In Matt 10:11, the meaning is obviously (2a) as listed above from BDAG.  This means ἄξιός might be better translated "appropriate" in a good sense for evangelists to stay - one who understands the importance of the work, who is sympathetic to the cause. and a person of upright and good repute. Ellicott observes for this verse:

> Enquire who in it is worthy.--The command was a plain practical rule.
>   The habits of Eastern hospitality would throw many houses open to the
>   preachers which would give no openings for their work, or even bring
>   on them an evil report. From these they were to turn away and to seek
>   out some one who, though poor, was yet of good repute, and willing to
>   receive them as messengers of glad tidings.

Such a selection is not trivial and would generally require inspired decisions, but Jesus promised to go with the disciples (Matt 28:20) so such requirements would be no obstacle.